# Web-RTC server-client

Tags: node.js, webrtc

There are my questions:

1. Is it possible to connect the browser with the server via WebRTC?
2. My server broadcast different audio channels and depending of what kind of button I click, I have to change the audio stream. Is it possible with webRTC?
3. In the server side I use nodejs with socketIO

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebRTC with a node server, but WebRTC is really a protocol for persistent communication between two clients.  Using socketIO will set up a persistent connection between a client and your server.

You might want to look into [PeerJS](https://github.com/peers/peerjs) if you are interested in setting up WebRTC handshaking from your node server.

WebRTC depends on STUN and TURN servers, which are pretty difficult to set up yourself.  There are some guides out there, but it is my understanding that this isn't something you would run through a basic node app.  Luckily Google provides a free STUN server that you can use to try things out and you will not need a TURN server for basic implementations (though you won't have a fallback when two clients can't communicate directly.)

[You can read more about WebRTC here.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my shot at answering your questions:

1) It depends on what you mean by connecting to a server with WebRTC. If you're talking about signaling then Node.js is definitely an option using WebSockets but you will need to define your own signaling protocol. If you are talking about media then you'll need a media server that support DTLS, SRTP and all the various media codecs (VP8, Opus, G.711, etc.). Take a look at Kurento for an open source option. We use Dialogic PowerMedia XMS for things like record/playback, transcoding, multiway, etc.

2)You can certainly open multiple peer connections from a single WebRTC client. Things like Simulcast are coming in future releases. More detail on what you are asking for here would help.

3)Not really a question so not sure how to answer this one.

Note that if you are working with media on the backend you will need a way to control the media server. JSR 309 is what we use as a media control interface. Kurento has a proprietary API. If you want to read more about our solution you can go here: http://www.wasdev.net/webrtc

Comment: Thanks @bpulito! I will be more precise. The client side, implemented with Angular, has img which change the color when somebody is speaking. In that case you can choose, talk or listen. If we choose listen, the client side receive the audio that already is in the server which is coming for another stream in real-time. That stream has to be played when the client click the button in the browser. And if we click talk, it has to record and send in the same time that we click the button.

Comment: The signalling protocol I set with nodeJS. I saw kurento as media server but it has too much latency for my app. Is it possible to exchange the audio by nodejs? Or is it better with webRTC and media server? Everything is new so even small help will be useful. Thanks @bpulito

Comment: @Ganbel We normally experience ~300ms latency with Kurento. Do you need lower than that? If you have latency issues, it could be due to a high CPU load. Are you using any CV filters?

Comment: @igracia Nice! I think, I could try if the latency is around 300ms. I have apache web server, that it proxies to one webSocket which is the owner of the audio. It could be possible to set that web socket as media server? I don't know if I mix the concepts or if its possible that, if I'm wrong which will the best solution for my problem? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Ganbel yap, you are missing the concepts :-P Media does not flow through the websocket, only signaling does. Have a look at [this documentation](https://www.kurento.org/docs/current/introducing_kurento.html) so you get a clearer view of the separation between signaling an media planes.

Comment: @igracia ok, got it! So how could I do to send my real time audio to media server and after create a webRTC connection between client and server to stream that audio? Thanks!